# Re-usable component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Trying to send params when a button is clicked on child component to parent component - How do I call the function in Parent component with a value I am getting from Child component: 
In Parent component I am trying to do something like this:

**Parent:**

```
<BtnToggle currentColor={this.state.activeColor} onClick={() => this.setColorBtn(this.state.setActColor)}/>

setActColor(color) {
   console.log(btnName+"parent");
}
```

**Child component:**

```
class BtnToggle extends Component { 

setActColor(color) {
    console.log(color);
    this.props.onClick(color);
  }      

render() {
            return (
              <span className="group">
                <button ref={(color) => { this.red = color; }} onClick={() => this.setActColor('red')} className={`btn-element ${(this.props.activeColor === 'red') ? 'btn-active' : ''}`}>Red</button>
                <button ref={(color) => { this.blue = color; }} onClick={() => this.setActColor('blue')} className={`btn-element ${(this.props.activeColor === 'blue') ? 'btn-active' : ''}`}>Blue</button>
              </span>
            );
          }
         }

        export default BtnToggle;
```

Comment: Can't get you clearly, What actually the requirement?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja updated the question.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja : basically when I am trying to call function from child component, I Need to pass in the color ( red/blue) - How do I pass it to the function in parent - which has some additional functionality - which child component does not need to bother about..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you are trying to update `active` button state from child to parent `component`. The below code will address you implement data flow from `child` to `parent` and vice-versa.

**child**

```
class BtnToggle extends Component {

  setActColor(color) {
    console.log(color);
    this.props.onClick(color);
  }

  render() {
    return ( < span className = "group" >
      <button onClick = {this.setActColor('red')} className = {`btn-element ${(this.props.activeColor === 'red') ? 'btn-active' : ''}`} > Red < /button> 
      <button onClick = {this.setActColor('blue')}
      className = {`btn-element ${(this.props.activeColor === 'blue') ? 'btn-active' : ''}`} > Blue < /button> 
      < /span>
    );
  }
}
```

**parent**

```
class Parent extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    activeColor: "red" //initial active state (color)
   }
  }

  setActColor(color) {
     console.log(color);
     this.setState({
      activeColor: color //this gets params from child component
     });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <BtnToggle activeColor={this.state.activeColor} onClick={this.setActColor}/>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it good, you are trying to send an param from child to a parent. Thus, if someone setActColor function is called from child that setActColor function call setColor function from a parent and pass an param to it...

You can do it like this :

```
class BtnToggle extends React.Component { 

setActColor(color, event) {
    this.props.setColor(color)
  }      

render() {
            return (
              <span className="group">
                <button onClick={this.setActColor.bind(this, "red")}>Red</button>
                <button onClick={this.setActColor.bind(this, "blue")}>Blue</button>
              </span>
            );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
        setColor(color){
            alert(color);
    }

        render(){
        return <BtnToggle setColor={this.setColor.bind(this)}/>
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1474/).